# Trigger jQuery Autocomplete manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete with some AJAX (the data isn't pulled until after they stop typing).  I would like to make it so once the data is found, Autocomplete will then pop-up as a search result.  This works, however only when I start typing again (the dropdown doesn't trigger until I type because it's not initialized until after I stop typing).

My code:

```
var availableTags = [
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby"
];
$('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0
});
    $('input#mainSearchBox').data('autocomplete').menu.active;
```

The last part was an attempt to activate autocomplete, but it fails.

Comment: You're using _autocomplete with some AJAX_. In that case, the popup will appear when (i) you've typed minLength characters (ii) delay milliseconds have passed since your last keystroke (iii) Ajax results have been fetched and processed. Are you sure you understand this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The [search method](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) should do the trick:

```
$('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete("search");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W56yq/)

Comment: Ah! OMG, I used:   $('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete('search', 'demo-value');

I should have removed that...

Comment: haha, the minLength is the key here. does not work without it.

Comment: yeah, the search method was spot on!

Comment: Make sure you set `minLength` to 0 when instantiating autocomplete. This enables it to show all options when the input is empty.

`autocomplete("search")` uses the current input value to search and `autocomplete("search", "")` will show all available values

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following script to toggle the autocomplete manually:

```
var textbox = $('input#mainSearchBox');
var autocompleteBox = textbox.autocomplete('widget');

// toggle the autocomplete widget
autocompleteBox.is(':hidden') ? 
    textbox.autocomplete('search', textbox.val()).focus() :
    autocompleteBox.hide();
```

This code can be found in the source of the [combobox example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) on the jquery autocomplete demo site (lines 127-141).

Answer (score 1):

For https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete, you can use:

```
$('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete("getSuggestions", $('input#mainSearchBox').val())
```