# jquery : how to fill a form sending key to trigger events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fill a form with jquery. 
This form displays an autocomplete list.
So I need it to be done with

I tried it that way:

```
$("input#where.form-control").focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 65 });
$("input#where.form-control").trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 65}));

var press = jQuery.Event("keyDown");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 66;
$("input#where.form-control").trigger(press);
```

But nothing happens.
Web page I try to make it work is : https://www.rdvmedicaux.com/

If you type in first letter, it display an autocomplete list of cities.

```
$("input#where.form-control").val('Paris') completes but does not trigger the automplete list
```

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686319/trigger-jquery-autocomplete-manually

Comment: This is not JQUERYUI autocomplete !